# Get keycode/key from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `select` tag in which I am giving option from `F1` to `F10`..Now when user press button any one from `F1` to `F10` then I have to detect.

```
<select id="forward_ckey">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="ESC" disabled>ESC</option>
    <option value="F1">F1</option>
    <option value="F2" disabled>F2</option>
    <option value="F3" selected>F3</option>
    <option value="F4" disabled>F4</option>
    <option value="F5" disabled>F5</option>
    <option value="F6">F6</option>
    <option value="F7">F7</option>
    <option value="F8">F8</option>
    <option value="F9">F9</option>
    <option value="F10">F10</option>
    <option value="F11">F11</option>
    <option value="F12">F12</option>
</select>

    $(document).unbind('keydown.g').bind('keydown.g', function (e) {
        var unicode = e.keyCode;            
        if (unicode == 'SELECTED VALUE KEYCODE') { //HERE "F3" KEYCODE
```

Output: If I press F3 and selected value is also F3 then it should execute code block in that..
The main problem I am facing is that I got `F3` from option value and getting keycode from keypress how to match both..Either I need key of pressed from keyboard or keycode of selected value from option

Demo

```js
           var selected_id = "";
           $('select').on('change', function() {
             selected_id = this.value;
           });
           $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
             var unicode = e.keyCode;
             alert("");
             if (unicode == selected_id) { //F3 KEYCODE or Key from `e`
               alert("");
             }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="play_ckey">
  <option value="default"></option>
  <option value="ESC" selected>ESC</option>
  <option value="F1">F1</option>
  <option value="F2" disabled>F2</option>
  <option value="F3" disabled>F3</option>
  <option value="F4" disabled>F4</option>
  <option value="F5" disabled>F5</option>
  <option value="F6">F6</option>
  <option value="F7">F7</option>
  <option value="F8">F8</option>
  <option value="F9">F9</option>
  <option value="F10">F10</option>
  <option value="F11">F11</option>
  <option value="F12">F12</option>
</select>
```

I got value from selected option but now How can I get key which is pressed by user or keycode of selected value from option to match in condition?

Comment: y downvote? any explanation?

Comment: You can see a list of useful keycodes here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes, but can you share some more code with us? It's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: I don't need keycode of that..I want key of pressed key from keyboard or keycode of selected value from option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the keycode of the corresponding selected value you need something like this:

```js
var keycodes = {'F1': 112, 'F2': 113, 'F3': 114, …};
var selectedValue = $('#forward_ckey').val();
var selectedKeycode = keycodes[selectedValue];
```

Comment: thnku so much..i thought about it but did not know how to do that..it helps

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm

Here's the sample:

```
function myKeyboard(e) {
    // gets called when any of the keyboard events are overheard
    keyCode = e.characterCode;
    alert(keyCode);
}
```

`Bind` the above function `myKeyboard()` on your element OR any other input / textarea box.

Also here's list of the keys and their character codes: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Also there's an other helpful guide as well: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

check this demo out: http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: Thanku you for sharing links..Actually I already know about events and keycodes and charcode but I was facing problem to get keycode from string value